# Is it possible to access top level interface outer of the class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am experimenting with dagger in Kotlin.

Let's say that i want to do something simple:

module:

```java
@Binds
abstract fun bindNotificationCreator(creator: NotificationCreator): NotificationCreatorBinder
```

usage:

```java
@Inject
lateinit var creator: NotificationCreatorBinder
```

NotificationCreator:

```java
class NotificationCreator @Inject constructor(): NotificationCreatorBinder
```

The problem is, that i need to create a separate file for interface.

Will it be possible to declare class and interface on one file for usage in dagger `@Bind`?

something like this:

```java
interface Binder{
    //TODO
}

class NotificationCreator @Inject constructor(): Binder
```

and then:

```java
@Binds
abstract fun bindNotificationCreator(creator: NotificationCreator): NotificationCreator.Binder
```

but i can't access to `NotificationCreator.Binder` outside `NotificationCreator` class

Comment: Try to import `Binder` (not `NotificationCreator.Binder`) , just check the path of the imported Binder.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I see where you going, but this is bad solution, as for me. Interface(in my case) is pointless without class. And should not be accessed from package

Comment: In this case place interface inside your class `class NotificationCreator() { interface Binder }`

Comment: @Demigod this is not possible. Class should implement this interface. Class can't implement an interface that inside this class

Comment: There isn't any `NotificationCreator.Binder` to access in the first place, if it isn't inside the class.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov i don't understand what you mean

Comment: @SerhiiPokrovskyi If you have `interface Binder { ... }; class NotificationCreator @Inject constructor(): Binder` then you have to refer to interface as `Binder`. It only makes sense to write `NotificationCreator.Binder` when it's declared inside `NotificationCreator` as in Demigod's comment. And then, yes, the outer class can't implement the nested interface.

Comment: Why don't you just put `NotificationCreator` and `NotificationCreatorBinder` into a single file? Unlike Java, there's no rule that you can only have one public class or interface per file.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov well, in my point of view, it will be the same. I want a convenient way to address an interface via class(*NotificationCreator .NotificationCreatorBinder *). Because this interface is useless without this class

Comment: Again: you simply can't do both things you want. You are out of luck.